# Необычный слайдер на базе Slick

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, slider, slick.js

Задумка такая: есть слайдер, у которого через 3 сек меняется backgroung-image и еще через 3 сек происходит переход на следующий слайд. В итоге мы получаем к примеру 3 слайда и 6 фонов (по 2 фона на каждый слайд). Пните куда копать.

фон - 3 сек / фон - 3 сек / scroll next

Такой еще вопрос, что лучше менять фоновое изображение одно на другое или менять картинку на картинку `<img>`?

Я просто не могу сообразить пока куда мне выводить изображения, чтоб потом js'ом ими управлять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не использовал эту библиотеку, но [следуя документации](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) предположу что можно сделать так:

```
var currentInterval = 0;
var getBackground = function () {};

$('.your-element').slick({ autoplaySpeed: 6000 })

$('.your-element').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    if (currentInterval) {
        clearInterval(currentInterval);
    }
});

$('.your-element').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
    currentInterval = setInterval(function() {
        getBackground();
    }, 3000);
});
```

Время отображения одного слайда - 6 секунд.
После переключения слайда создаем 3-х секундный интервал с функцией и в этой функции меняем background. 
Перед переключением слайда очищаем старый, но не ставим новый интервал, тк у нас есть еще неучтенное время на переключения.

И запускаем еще один интервал при старте галереи.

Comment: Решил вопрос на основе вашего ответа, спасибо! Вот пример https://jsfiddle.net/qstbondw/4/